# Python 3.x (beazley): __context__ vs __cause__ attributes in exception handling

Tags: python, python-3.x

In 'Chained Exceptions' - Beazley pg:626

```
try:
  pass
except ValueError as e:
  raise SyntaxError('foo bar') from e
```

Here, if ValueError is raised and SyntaxError is then raised.. 'e' contains `__cause__` which points to the ValueError Traceback. He goes on to say:

```
A more subtle example of exception chaining involves exceptions raised within
another exception handler. For example:
def error(msg):
  print(m)          # Note: typo is intentional (m undefined)
try:
  statements
except ValueError as e:
  error("Couldn't parse configuration")
```

Here, 'error' generates an inadvertent exception. What i don't understand is this bit:

```
For implicit chaining, the _ _context_ _ attribute of an exception instance 
e contains a reference to previous exception.
```

Why is he saying that 'e' contains a reference in `__context__` to the exception generated by 'error' ?? Is that correct? Surely, the exception generated by 'error' will refer to 'e'?

Comment: How are those statements ordered/organized in the text?  I don't think "an exception instance `e`" is necessarily referring to the exception `e` in that code example.  It just means "any exception instance that arises in handling of an earlier exception".

Comment: Additionally, how would you go about using `__context__` if the exception is generated implicitly? Book pages: http://imgur.com/bwpYq8T http://imgur.com/inZQv5J

Comment: Those screenshots seem consistent with what I suggested.  What do you mean "how would you go about using `__context__`"?  If you catch an exception `e`, you can access `e.__context__` to see if it has a context.

Comment: `__context__` is part of an exception-object that's implicitly generated - if it's being generated implicitly, how do you get your paws on it? exception object 'e' contains `__cause__` NOT `__context__`

Comment: I've written an answer below.  There is no implicitly generated exception.  What can be explicit or implicit is the *relationship* between two exceptions (i.e., you can explicitly say whether one caused the other, or one can arise during the course of handling the other, with no explicit relationship).

Comment: "Here, if ValueError is raised and SyntaxError is then raised.. 'e' contains `__cause__` which points to the ValueError Traceback" - No it does not. `e` is the ValueError. The newly created SyntaxError contains a reference to the ValueError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked one question in the question and a separate question in the comments.

To your question in the question:

I don't think "an exception instance e" is necessarily referring to the exception e in that code example. It just means "any exception instance that arises in handling of an earlier exception".  So that statement just means that if one exception (say `e1`) is being handled, and during that handling another exception (`e2`) is raised, then `e2` will propagate, and `e2.__context__` will be set to `e1`.

As to your question in the comment, I think you are misunderstanding.  There is no "exception being generated implicitly".  What can be implicit or explicit is the *relationship* between *two* exceptions.  By using `raise ... from ...` you make explicit the relationship between the two (i.e., one was "deliberately" created from the other).  If you don't use `from`, the relationship is implicit (the second one just somehow occurred during the handling of the first).

The way it works is that if in the handling of one exception, a new exception is raised, then the new exception will have the old exception in its `__context__` attribute of the new exception.  If, however, the new exception includes a `from` clause (`raise NewException from OldException`), then the new exception will additionally have the old exception in its `__cause__` attribute.

Examples:

```
>>> try:
...     try:
...         raise ValueError("ValueError")
...     except ValueError as first:
...         raise TypeError("TypeError")
... except TypeError as second:
...     print("The exception was", repr(second))
...     print("Its __context__ was", repr(second.__context__))
...     print("Its __cause__ was", repr(second.__cause__))
The exception was TypeError('TypeError',)
Its __context__ was ValueError('ValueError',)
Its __cause__ was None

>>> try:
...     try:
...         raise ValueError("ValueError")
...     except ValueError as first:
...         raise TypeError("TypeError") from first
... except TypeError as second:
...     print("The exception was", repr(second))
...     print("Its __context__ was", repr(second.__context__))
...     print("Its __cause__ was", repr(second.__cause__))
The exception was TypeError('TypeError',)
Its __context__ was ValueError('ValueError',)
Its __cause__ was ValueError('ValueError',)
```