# Exception object and missing __context__ and __cause__ attributes in IDE

Tags: python

The python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions
and this SO question mention the `__cause__` and `__context__` attributes on an exception object.
[Python 3.x (beazley): __context__ vs __cause__ attributes in exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924045/python-3-x-beazley-context-vs-cause-attributes-in-exception-handling#26925676)

However, when using a debugger to inspect an exception object (with the debuggers set to work on a `raise`) the exception object doesn't appear to have these attributes and just appears as a tuple.
(eg from my debugger - pycharm) https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VNQC.jpg

This occured with the debugger started based on the raise on the last line.

```py
    try:
        response = requests.request(method, url, json=payload, headers=HEADERS)
    except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as e:
        logger.exception("Api unavailable")
        raise errors.Unavailable('Api unavailable') from e
    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        logger.exception("Api HTTP error")
        try:
            raw_data = response.json()
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            raise errors.ApiHTTPError(f'{response.status_code}, {response.text}',
                                      text=response.text) from e
        api_errors = raw_data.get('errors')
        message = raw_data.get('message')
        raise errors.ApiHTTPError(f'HTTP Error {response.status_code}, {message}, {api_errors}',  text=response.text,
                                  api_errors=api_errors) from e
```

errors.py

```py
class SwitcherError(Exception):
    pass


class Unavailable(SwitcherError):
    pass


class ApiHTTPError(SwitcherError):
    def __init__(self, message=None, text=None, api_errors=None):
        self.text = text
        self.message = message
        self.errors = api_errors

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message


class ApiJsonError(SwitcherError):
    def __init__(self, message=None, text=None):
        self.text = text
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message


class ApiError(SwitcherError):
    def __init__(self, message, status_code,  data, status=None,):
        self.message = message
        self.status_code = status_code
        self.data = data
        self.status = status

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `__exception__` thing isn't an exception. It looks like PyCharm has taken [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) and stuffed it into an `__exception__` variable. The exception is the second tuple element, and that's where you should be looking for `__cause__` and `__context__`.

Comment: Thanks that helped. It seems as if pycharm is doing something a little bit different as doing `sys.exec.info()` whilst the debugger is frozen gives the earlier exception which is the __cause__ of the following one. I think Pycharm puts the final exception inside a variable __exception__ which looks to mimic doing sys.exc_info() from the calling frame. In the debugger console I can get the full details of the error by doing as you suggested `error= __exception__[1]` and then `error.__cause__` and `error.__context__` work as expected.

Comment: pycharm uses pdb as the debugger which also assigns an exception to the __exception__ name in the debugger. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241200/how-can-i-see-the-details-of-an-exception-in-pythons-debugger

Comment: @Yunti: This doesn't quite look like the pdb behavior. I don't think pdb keeps the traceback in `__exception__`.

Comment: You are right pycharm doesn't use pdb, so there are some differences. Instead it looks like they use pydev https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/05/debugger-interview-with-pydev-and-pycharm/.